# Answers involving ones own interpretation of the work

Tags: discussion, answers

Are answers that stem from our own personal interpretation of the work useful and kosher here?

I recently answered [Was Harry Potter killed and then brought back to life?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4602/1109) and my answer was completely based on how I interpreted the scene referenced in the book/movie without me needing to go to a wiki or outside source other than the book itself.

Is first hand research allowed?

Comment: Isn't a comment enough for a personal opinion?

Answer (score 5):

A interpretation could be good, if it's backed with several fact and explanation that lead to this interpretation. However, it could be contradicted/overpowered by other things like citation and/or interview of the author.

The problem with your answer was that it was contradicted with some element from the book.

An other example of this is in [Who *really* wrote the Rama sequels?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1685/who-really-wrote-the-rama-sequels/1707#1707). My answer is a citation and the other is an assumption. Both are valid answer, but the community judged the citation more relevant.